# Disable automatic VBA window opening while opening an Excel document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an `excel` document and I added some `vb script` to find the password of the protected file. I took this script from some internet forum. After that, whenever I open this excel sheet the `vba` window also opens automatically. I want to disable this. Could someone help me understanding the issue here? If I send this file to another person over email, will he face same issue while opening this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any one who opens that file will see the same dialog, better avoided.
You should delete that VBA from the document.

Perhaps the simplest way would be to save your `.xlsm` document as `.xlsx`,
which you should do anyway. It's not nice to send anyone a `.xlsm` document.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed those modules which I added earlier , and then I saved the `vba` project. This resolved my issue.